# HTML script (type/javascript) to cURL PHP

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm trying to post this script with PHP via cURL;

```
<script async=1 type=text/javascript src=//trackcmp.net/convert?actid=10000&e=info@email.com&c=1&v=100&r=&u=https://www.website.com/></script>
```

I've tried the following cURL;

```
$conversion_value = isset($args['conversion_value']) ? $args['conversion_value'] : "";
        
if(empty($conversion_value)){
    return false;
}

$window_location_href = "www.website.com";
$document_referrer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : "";

$trackcmp_email = 'info@email.com';
$trackcmp_conversion = '1';
$trackcmp_conversion_value = $conversion_value;
$trackcmp = [];
$trackcmp['src'] = 'https://trackcmp.net/convert';
$trackcmp['params'] = array('actid' => '10000', 'e' => urlencode($trackcmp_email), 'c' => $trackcmp_conversion, 'v' => $trackcmp_conversion_value, 'r' => $document_referrer, 'u' => $window_location_href);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $trackcmp['src']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $trackcmp['params']);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/javascript';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Did I forgot something cURL wise or is it just not going to work?

I would like for these values to be posted to said URL via some sort of webhook eventually.

EDIT:
Apparently I've been over-thinking the problem. The reply I've marked as 'answer' solved this problem for me.

Comment: Shouldn't `actid` be `contactid`?

Comment: No, actid = the ID of an account. The Javascript mentioned above works. But since you can't activate JavaScript if you're not a `client` that part of the code doesn't get send. Therefor I wanted to turn it into a cURL via PHP and send the data through acting as javascript content.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a post when you should use get if you want to mimick the request

Comment: By removing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); and curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $trackcmp['params']);` and adding http_build_query to the CURLOPT_URL it also doesn't seem to work sadly. Also tried setting CURLOPT_POST to 0.

Comment: @Pale The documentation showed it as contactid.  Have your tried `/curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);`  or `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');`

Comment: @Misunderstood I've tried both the setopt's and a combination of either. This doesn't seem to work. I've also tried to change actid to contactid just to make sure that wasn't it and that also didn't work.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the current script? What have you tried to resolve the problem? That's a lot of code for a simple `GET` request. Also, why is this question tagged with JS, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: @Nico I removed the JS tag.
- The script at the top (If placed on a website) is sending a conversion value to a contact in ActiveCampaign (This works if the site is manually called by a user)
I would like to take out the user aspect of this functionality. We have some sort of webhook/trigger system that executes code based on other webhooks and trigger.
For example a user orders something which costs X then would like to forward X via that specific script to ActiveCampaign as said conversion. This system of ours uses PHP.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your quesiton by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase He posted the JS code that was working. He just needed to convert it to curl.  It was very clear to me.

Comment: @Misunderstood "He posted the JS code" - where did that happen? I don't see any JS code in the question

Comment: @NicoHaase Very first line.

Comment: @Misunderstood sorry, the current post does not contain JS code. The first line in the post contains HTML markup that links to any external ressource. If the JS code behind that link is relevant to the question, it should be added to it. An external link can change any second, and such a change would make the whole question useless

Comment: The code is very old.  It's more of a hack, it is not being used as intended.  It's similar to using file_get_contents() in PHP.  And it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your request looks like to the trackcmp.net server

```
Content-Length: 618
Content-Type: text/javascript; boundary=------------------------9923620be574b58c
Accept: */*
BODY=
--------------------------9923620be574b58c
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="actid"
10000
--------------------------9923620be574b58c
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="e"
info%40email.com
--------------------------9923620be574b58c
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="c"
1
--------------------------9923620be574b58c
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="v"
--------------------------9923620be574b58c
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="r"
--------------------------9923620be574b58c
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="u"
--------------------------9923620be574b58c--
```

Remove the post fields.
Add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);`
Use this URL:

```
https://trackcmp.net/convert?actid=10000&e=info@email.com&c=1&v=100&r=&u=https://www.website.com
```

And the received GET data will look like it should:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
actid=10000&e=info@email.com&c=1&v=100&r=&u=https://www.website.com
```

So here is your curl code:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/javascript';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://trackcmp.net/convert?actid=10000&e=info@email.com&c=1&v=100&r=&u=https://www.website.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Setting `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` to `true` is unnecessary as this is the default value anyway

Comment: @DarkBee And you can set it to false and it's still a GET.  It's more of a documenting statement than an actual option.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and answer. I feel like there is some check happening behind the scenes at 'trackcmp.net' even with this GET request it does not appear to work. Not sure if it needs some sort of human input like how it's done with the JavaScript.

Comment: Try putting the header back.  text/javascript in the header has no affect on a GET request.  But may be their server is looking for it.